# Can I run many Loaders at the same time in the same activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loader, asynctaskloader

I have a doubt about the use of `Loader`. 
In my case, I call my own class that extends `AsyncTaskLoader` and return a `List` of MyObject.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<MyObject>> {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
       getLoaderManager().initLoader(2_ID, null, this);
       getLoaderManager().initLoader(3_ID, null, this);
       ...
  }

}
```

**My question is**: can I run many `Loader` at the same time on the same `Activity`?

Will every Loader, when its `loadInBackground()` method is finished, call the `onLoadFinished()` method impemented in my `Activity`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can run many loaders at a time in one activity with unique ids, because Loader is a Asynchronous process. Please find below sample template.

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);
        initLoaders();
    }

    private void initLoaders() {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, null);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(2, null, null);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(3, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = null;
        switch (id) {
            case 1:
                cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI,
                        PROJECTION, selection, null, null);
                break;

            case 2:
                cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI,
                        PROJECTION, selection, null, null);
                break;

            case 3:
                cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI,
                        PROJECTION, selection, null, null);
                break;
        }
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        switch (loader.getId()) {
            case 1:
                if (data != null && data.getCount() > 0)
                    setData1();
                break;

            case 2:
                if (data != null && data.getCount() > 0)
                    setData2();
                break;

            case 3:
                if (data != null && data.getCount() > 0)
                    setData3();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
}
```